# My explanatory variable is also count data, is there a way I can still do a Poisson Regression?

Tags: poisson-distribution, assumptions, count-data, poisson-regression

I'm thinking of performing a Poisson regression on a dataset that I have. However, both the x and the y variables are based on counts.

One of the assumptions related to Poisson regression is that the explanatory variables must be continuous, dichotomous or ordinal.

Is there a workaround I can use, such as scaling the explanatory variable to allow it to conform to the assumptions for this type of regression.

The below dataset is entirely fictitious, though as an illustration, this is the similar type of data that I'm using in my real life situation.

Thanks for any advice you're will to provide.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! There is no assumption about predictors being continuous in Poisson regression. Observations are assumed independent, and the response to follow a Poisson distribution. And the model can only capture a log-linear association between predictors and response. It is likely you will not need a workaround. It is probably wise to check residual plots after fitting the model. It is not very helpful to provide an image of example data. Providing this as R code would probably increase the likelihood of more specific suggestions.

Comment: Re: "One of the assumptions related to Poisson regression is that the explanatory variables must be continuous, dichotomous or ordinal."  Could you tell us where you learned this?  It is such an unusual and narrow restriction as to make us suppose your source must have had an extremely specialized application in mind; or perhaps it conceives of "poisson regression" differently than its conventional meaning.

Comment: In practice the main point of a Poisson regression is the functional form $y = \exp(Xb)$ and a marginal Poisson assumption isn't assumed even for the response.

Comment: Already answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336919/can-count-data-be-used-as-the-independent-variable-in-binomial-logistic-regressi